# How to correctly type redux-thunk actions & mapDispatchToProps with redux 4.0.1, redux-thunk 2.3.0 & typescript 3.1.3

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, dispatch

I'm updating the dependencies in my project (redux 4.0.1, redux-thunk 2.3.0, typescript 3.1.3) and I'm having a very hard time finding the correct typings for redux-thunk in both my action declaration as my mapDispatchToProps declaration.

For example, I have the following actions:

*Normal redux action*

```
export interface UpdateRowContent {
    type: typeof Actions.UPDATE_ROW_CONTENT;
    payload: React.ReactNode[];
}
export const updateRowContent: ActionCreator<Action> = (content: React.ReactNode[]) => {
    return { type: Actions.UPDATE_ROW_CONTENT, payload: content};
};
```

*Redux-thunk action*

```
export interface ToggleModalShown {
    type: typeof Actions.TOGGLE_MODAL_SHOWN;
    payload: {
        isShown: boolean;
        targetType: TargetType;
        packageItemId?: string;
    };
}
export function toggleModalShown(
    isShown: boolean,
    targetType: TargetType,
    packageItemId?: string,
): any {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
        if (isShown) {
            dispatch(clearForm());
        } else if (packageItemId) {
            dispatch(fillForm(packageItemId));
        }
        dispatch({
            type: Actions.TOGGLE_MODAL_SHOWN,
            payload: {isShown: isShown, targetType: targetType, packageItemId: packageItemId ? packageItemId : null},
        });
    };
}
```

My mapDispatchToProps is as follows:

```
type DispatchType = Dispatch<Action> | ThunkDispatch<IState, any, Action>;

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: DispatchType) {
    return {
        updateRowContent: (content: React.ReactNode[]) => {
            dispatch(updateRowContent(content));
        },
        toggleModalShown: (isShown: boolean, targetType: TargetType) => {
            dispatch(toggleModalShown(isShown, targetType));
        },
    };
}
```

All the things I find online tell me to type the mapDispatchToProps as `ThunkDispatch<S,E,A>`, which is what I'm currently trying to do.
The guides tell me to type the actual thunk-action as `ActionCreator<ThunkAction<R,S,E,A>>`

When I try to use `ActionCreator<ThunkAction<void,IState,any,Action>>` instead of `any` as type for my redux-thunk, I get the error `Argument of type 'ActionCreator<ThunkAction<void, GoState, any, Action<any>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action<any>'.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I made a silly mistake in my dispatch typing...

```
type DispatchType = Dispatch<Action> | ThunkDispatch<IState, any, Action>;
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: DispatchType) {...}
```

should be

```
type DispatchType = Dispatch<Action> & ThunkDispatch<IState, any, Action>;
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: DispatchType) {...}
```

After fixing that I found out that my redux-thunk action type should be

```
export function toggleModalShown(): ThunkAction<void, IState, any, Action> {...}
```

instead of

```
export function toggleModalShown(): ActionCreator<ThunkAction<void, IState, any, Action>> {...}
```